# Error stray '#' in program

Tags: c++, macros, g++, c-preprocessor

I would like to define a macro based on whether `-std=c++0x` is used.
If I try the macro below I have error `error stray '#' in program`.

Is the code below incorrect / is it allowed C++ to use preprocessor `#if / #endif`  within a `#define`?

```
   #define DEF_ME (p) \
   #if  __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ \
   #endif
```

I am using g++ 4.4.7 in Linux.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is the code below incorrect / is it allowed C++ to use preprocessor `#if` / `#endif` within a `#define`?

No, that’s not allowed. But you can use the opposite to get the same result:

```
#if  __GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__
#   define DEF_ME (p) one way
#else
#   define DEF_ME (p) another way
#endif
```